# To each his own problems

Tags: sentence

is this sentence correct:

"To each his own problems." to means "everybody has their problems."

Thank you!

Comment: No. The set phrase is just "to each his own," coming from the Latin [suum cuique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suum_cuique). You can't use a set phrase any other way.

Comment: Well, I've heard "To each his own X" many times, but it does indeed draw on the idiomatic "To each his own" expression, with perhaps a sarcastic/ironic twist.

Answer (score 3):

**To each his own** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/To+Each+His+Own) idiom

> each person has the right to make choices.

In a discussion about a problem, a comment of **to each his own** means a possible different interpretation of such, not that each person has the same problems, a different problem, or any problems at all.